# Empty colorbar using basemap.pcolor in an ImageGrid

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap, subplot

The following code produces the image I want, but the colourbar is blank/white, and doesn't match the data:

```
def plot_array(da, ax=None, shift=True):
    """plots an array of lat by lon on a coastline map"""

    m = basemap.Basemap()
    m.drawcoastlines()
    m.pcolormesh(da.lon, y=da.lat, data=da.T, latlon=True)

    return m

# 'monthly mean' is an xarray DataArray

fig = plt.figure(0, (14, 8))
grid = ImageGrid(fig, 111, nrows_ncols=(3, 4), axes_pad=0.3,
                 cbar_mode='single', cbar_location="bottom",)
for i, m in enumerate(months):
    plt.sca(grid[i])
    plot_array(monthly_mean.sel(month=i + 1))
    plt.title(m)
plt.suptitle("{b} - {y} monthly means".format(b=benchmark, y=year))
# plt.colorbar()
plt.tight_layout()

os.makedirs("plots/monthly_means/{y}".format(y=year), exist_ok=True)
plt.savefig("plots/monthly_means/{y}/{b}_{y}.png".format(b=benchmark, y=year))
plt.close()
```

[image: blank colorbar]

Is there something else I need to do to get the colorbar working with ImageGrid, or do ImageGrid and Basemap just not play well together?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I understand, it's not a Basemap problem.  The `ImageGrid()` call just sets up a blank set of axes for the colorbar that can be passed to `plt.colorbar()` via the `cax` argument.  By default `ImageGrid()` has the argument `cbar_set_cax=True`, which sets the `cax` attribute on each of the subplots.  You can then pass this to `colorbar()`:

```
...
plt.colorbar(cax=grid[0].cax)
plt.tight_layout()
...
```

That will just use the currently active axes to determine the colorbar data range, so it'll only be consistent with the final plot.  You're going to have to use combinations of `vmin/vmax` with `pcolormesh()` to ensure consistency across all the plots.

Comment: when I try to use `plt.colorbar(cax=grid[0].cax)`, I get an error:

`RuntimeError: No mappable was found to use for colorbar creation. First define a mappable such as an image (with imshow) or a contour set (with contourf).`


and if I try `plt.colorbar(plt.gca(), cax=grid[0].cax)` I get the error `AttributeError: 'CbarAxes' object has no attribute 'autoscale_None'`

Finally, if I try `plt.colorbar(grid[0],cax=grid[0].cax)` I get the error 
`AttributeError: 'LocatableAxes' object has no attribute 'autoscale_None`

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Using Serentiy's answer below fixes this issue

Comment: @user2472441 Probably sort of.  That `plt.colorbar(pcm)` is adding a new colorbar instance rather than replacing the one already established by `ImageGrid`.  The original blank one is still there underneath the new one - try setting `orientation="vertical"` in the colorbar call to see them both.  If you don't replace the original one it may be visible with some figure sizes.

Answer (score 4):

Matplotlib can not define what you want to plot on a colorbar. Write like

```
...
pcm = m.pcolormesh(da.lon, y=da.lat, data=da.T, latlon=True)
plt.colorbar(pcm)
...
```